# Else/If statement with Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have to create a function that returns the string Elementary School if age is below 13, Secondary School if age is between 13 and 18 (both inclusive), and College in all other cases. Can someone tell me why my code isn't passing?

```
 function whichSchool(age) {
  // Your code in here ...
  if (age < 13); { 

    return ("Elementary School");
  }

   else if (age >= 13 && age <= 18); { 

    return ("Secondary School");
  }

  else if (age >= 19); {

    return ("College");

  }
}
```

The automated evaluator has errors with both 'else if' statements.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't put a semicolon `;` after the conditions: `if (age < 13) { `

Comment: Use a debugging tool to realize that your code is full of errors.  **Hint**: `;` are incorrectly placed in your code.

Comment: Remove the `;` after the before each if bracket, and try to learn the basics of the language before asking such elementary questions

Comment: Google `browser console` - it will change your life!

Comment: I was pointed in the direction of Overflow by my professor (new to javascript)- so yes, currently learning the basics Chacha. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't put semi colons after your if-else if 's boolean argument.

```
function whichSchool(age) {
// Your code in here ...
if (age < 13){ 

 return ("Elementary School");
}

else if (age >= 13 && age <= 18){ 

return ("Secondary School");
}

else if (age >= 19){

return ("College");

  }
}
```

This is a fix for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ";"

```
function whichSchool(age) {
  // Your code in here ...
  if (age < 13) { 

    return ("Elementary School");
  }

   else if (age >= 13 && age <= 18) { 

    return ("Secondary School");
  }

  else if (age >= 19) {

    return ("College");

  }
}
```